# Are non-Jews considered Hashem's "children"?

Tags: gentiles, theology, children

The pasuk says "banim atem lashem elokeichem," referring to us. Is there a drasha anywhere (or another source) that says that non-Jews are not called Hashem's children? (I don't think this would really make it an issue to tell non-Jews that "we are all God's children," as we would be using the words colloquially and not in a halachic sense, but curious nonetheless).

Comment: That would seem to be the implication of this mishnah: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.3.14?lang=bi

Comment: Moshe tells Pharaoh, in G-d's name, that the Jews are "G-d's *firstborn* child", implying that everyone else are also children. This is precisely Sforno's comment there.

Comment: As you can see, there are answers both ways. Can you narrow the question a little. Sounds like you are implying there is a "halachic" sense, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Shalom (1) An only child is also a firstborn. (2) [Sforno on Exodus 4:22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sforno_on_Exodus.4.22.1?lang=bi) says: "מכל מקום יחשב ישראל אצלי נכבד מכלם באשר הוא בני עובד **כמו בן** מאהבה, לא **כעבד** מאהבת שכר ויראת עונש". He seems to contrast Israel-as-son with [other-]nations-as-servants. He also splits first[born] from son ("ראשון לעבודתי"), contrasted with "בתעות כל האומות מעלי". He doesn't refer there to other nations also being are G-d's sons, but seems to read the verse as saying "Israel is my [only?] son who is first".

Comment: "_(I don't think this would really make it an issue to tell non-Jews that 'we are all God's children,'_ ... _)_"Based on the Mishnah linked to by Joel K, it might be better to tell them "we are all God's beloved creations".

Answer (score 0):

If you do not object to interpreting a prophet yourself, I would consider the words of Amos 9:7:

```
הֲל֣וֹא כִבְנֵי֩ כֻשִׁיִּ֨ים אַתֶּ֥ם לִ֛י בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל נְאֻם־יְהֹוָ֑ה הֲל֣וֹא אֶת־יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל הֶעֱלֵ֙יתִי֙ מֵאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם וּפְלִשְׁתִּיִּ֥ים מִכַּפְתּ֖וֹר וַאֲרָ֥ם מִקִּֽיר׃


To Me, O Israelites, you are just like the Cushites—declares the LORD.
True, I brought Israel up from the land of Egypt, but also the Philistines from Caphtor and the Arameans from Kir.
```